# return statement being skipped inside 2 loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, path, return

I am using the following method that i found online and tweaked to find files in a given directory using only the file's name:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the file to be searched.. " );
   String name = scan.next();
   System.out.println("Enter the directory where to search ");
   String directory = scan.next();
   System.out.println(findFile(name,new File(directory)));
}

public static String findFile(String name,File file)
{
    String correctFilePath = null;
    ArrayList<String> possiblePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    String nameToFind = "anyname";
    if(list!=null)
        for (File fil : list)
        {
            if (fil.isDirectory())
            {
                findFile(name,fil);
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
            {
                possiblePaths.add(fil.getParent());
            }
        }
    // Here, all the files containing the name of the file that I am looking
    // for have been already added to the ArrayList.
    // However, I know what the ending of the path is,
    // which is what I am checking in the following loops
    String filePath;
    for (int i = 0; i < possiblePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        filePath = possiblePaths.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < nameToFind.length(); j++)
        {
            if (filePath.charAt(filePath.length()     - (j + 1)) ==
                nameToFind.charAt(nameToFind.length() - (j + 1))    )
            {
                if (j == nameToFind.length() - 1)
                {
                    correctFilePath = filePath;
                    return correctFilePath;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return correctFilePath;
}
```

Right now, what happens is that once the file is found and `correctFilePath = filePath` is executed, the return statement is being skipped, and I am brought back to the beginning of the *i* loop, with `correctFilePath = null`. How could i fix this?

Comment: What makes you think that an unconditionally line after an executed line is not executed? It seems very unlikely. Please  explain and make a [mre] to demonstrate.

Comment: @Yunnosch I followed the whole program with a debugger with a breakpoint on the return statement, it was able to enter the if statement when it was supposed to, but didn't return anything

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't return anything"? What do you see if you output the returned variable before returning and the return value afterwards (i.e. from the caller)? Output it within a "frame", e.g. print `<` before and `>` after, to make sure that you can tell "nothing"/emptystring from single blank or newline.

Comment: Put an unconditional output at the start of the function. I still want a [mre], because I suspect that the problem is outside of the shown code. The output would allow to tell when the function unintentionally gets called again....

Comment: Describing indentation is hard. I took the liberty to just apply my preferred one, because I think you wanted to use mine. You are of course free to undo or tune to your liking.

Comment: I think there is a risky lack of `{}` inside the `if`, around the `for`. I recommend to double check and put explicity `{}` where you expect them.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, i took away that return statement and the `correctFilePath = filePath;` statement, and replaced both by an indication of the desired String's position inside of the ArrayList, which i set to static.

Comment: Well done finding a solution for your problem and providing it here. I am a little disappointed that the cause of the problem was not found (or not explained). But that can come in a different answer. Finding and sharing an, albeit indirect, solution is good StackOverflow style.